# Turn On/Off Wifi remotely by sending SMS Command

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to IOS Programming..
For IOS Device.   I am trying to build an app in which,  by sending SMS command Wifi can  turn ON/OFF remotely..
please suggest me.

THANKS in Advance..

Comment: Turn Wifi off on the phone? Or somewhere else using the phone?

Comment: yes,On the phone by SMS command through other iPhone

Comment: I like the question but for what reason would you want to do that? It would make more sense to turn off somewhere else when sent SMS message.

Comment: i have 2 iPhone and i am trying to control on Wifi On/Off by sending SMS to each other ...

Answer (score 2):

No, on a non-jailbroken phone, you cannot get any data on SMS messages or phone calls. They are entirely walled off from your application.

If your device is jailbroken, then you could monitor the sqllite database located on your phone at:
/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db